# How to find the maximum value within a loop in R

Tags: r, loops

I have an expression

```
 qbinom(0.05, n, .47) - 1
```

and I want to create a loop which iterates this expression over n for n = (20,200). For each iteration of this loop, this function will produce a number. I want to take the maximum of the 180 numbers it will produce. So, something like.

```
 for (n in 20:200) {
   max(qbinom(0.05, n, .47)-1)
```

But I'm not sure how exactly to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Might be best as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: not that it really matters here, but the more representative code would be `max(qnorm(0.05, 20:200, 0.47)-1)`

Comment: 20:200 is 181 numbers, not 180

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, I will show you how to do this with a loop.

```
n <- 20:200
MAX = -Inf    ## initialize maximum
for (i in 1:length(n)) {
  x <- qbinom(0.05, n[i], 0.47) - 1
  if (x > MAX) MAX <- x
  }

MAX
# [1] 81
```

Note, I am not keeping a record of all 181 values generated. Each value is treated as a temporary value and will be overwritten in the next iteration. In the end, we only have a single value `MAX`.

If you want to at the same time retain all the records, we need first initialize a vector to hold them.

```
n <- 20:200
MAX = -Inf    ## initialize maximum
x <- numeric(length(n))    ## vector to hold record
for (i in 1:length(n)) {
  x[i] <- qbinom(0.05, n[i], 0.47) - 1
  if (x[i] > MAX) MAX <- x[i]
  }

## check the first few values of `x`
head(x)
# [1] 5 5 6 6 6 7

MAX
# [1] 81
```

---

Now I am showing the **vectorization** solution.

```
max(qbinom(0.05, 20:200, 0.47) - 1)
# [1] 81
```

R functions related to probability distributions are vectorized **in the same fashion**. For those related to binomial distributions, you can read `?rbinom` for details.

Note, the vectorization is achieved with recycling rule. For example, by specifying:

```
qbinom(0.05, 1:4, 0.47)
```

R will first do recycling:

```
   p: 0.05    0.05    0.05    0.05
mean:    1       2       3       4
  sd: 0.47    0.47    0.47    0.47
```

then evaluate

```
qbinom(p[i], mean[i], sd[i])
```

**via a C-level loop**.

---

**Follow-up**

> How would I be able to know which of the 20:200 corresponds to the maximum using the vectorization solution?

We can use

```
x <- qbinom(0.05, 20:200, 0.47) - 1
i <- which.max(x)
# [1] 179
```

Note, `i` is the position in vector `20:200`. To get the `n` you want, you need:

```
(20:200)[i]
# 198
```

The maximum is

```
x[i]
# [1] 81
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I be able to know which of the 20:200 to which the maximum corresponds using the vectorization solution?

Comment: But here I do not have qnorm, I have qbinom. Namely, I am trying to find both the maximum value n and the corresponding k so that the probability of getting at most k out of n is as close to 0.05 as possible. K is the output of the expression qbinom(0.05, n, 0.47) - 1

Comment: If I do max(qbinom(0.05, 20:200, 0.47) - 1), the output is 81. This means that my k is 81, but is there a way I can find out which n from 20:200 it corresponds to?